# Storing items generated in a loop in a variable or array without using files

Tags: linux, bash

I am doing this within github actions and I have a for loop

```
items="item1 item2 item3"
version=$(date +%s)

for item in $items; do 
    # some code
    echo "category/$item:$version" | cut -d '/' -f2- | tee -a list_all_items.txt;   
done
```

And this is fine. I get the output I need in that text file but I am trying to avoid working with text files, and **I don't know how to store the output in some kind of variable/array I can later re-use.**

I really need to store whatever's in `list_all_items.txt` in a variable, and I can do that outside the `for` loop,  but is it possible to achieve it within `for` loop?

EDIT: I edited the script to be reproducible.

The output (`list_all_items.txt)`:

```
item1:1649946431 item2:1649946431 item3:1649946431
```

etc.
So it's a string with values separated by space.

Comment: A variable for use within the same actions job, or to be used later in a different job within the same workflow?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and modify your script to a [mre]. We cannot run your incomplete script. What data does your script produce? What kind of variable do you want to get? An array? A string with values separated by space? Do you need the output both in the variable and on stdout? How do you want to use the variable? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: @jordanm I edited the script. A variable is for use in multiple steps within the same job.

Comment: @Bodo I edited the script. I want to get a variable which can be used in multiple steps within the same job, it would be the best if it's env var. I need the output in the variable, I don't need on stdout.

Comment: the script you've provided does not generate the output you've shown; the code generates: `category/item1:1649947065 \n category/item2:1649947065 \n category/item3:1649947065`; please confirm if you want the `category/` stripped from the strings; also, what do you want stored in the variable ... 3x strings on 3x lines ... or 3x strings on a single line separated by a space?

Comment: The original title was talking about "how to [do things with] tee in a for loop", but you're trying to *not* use files, so you want to *not* use tee. Edited the title to focus on what you want to accomplish, not what you're trying to get away from.

Comment: @markp-fuso I edited the script and `cut -d '/' -f2- ` will cut the `category/`.  I want 3x strings on 3x lines.

Comment: BTW, in general, using space-separated strings is suboptimal -- much of the reasoning behind [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) also applies to space-separated sequences. Use arrays, _really_.

Comment: @norskprove, once you have things in an array you can write that array out to a list of lines, or in space-separated form, or in any other format you want. For example, `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` writes each element of `array` to a separate line.

Comment: eliminate the need for `cut` by removing `category/` from the `echo` call

Comment: The other thing you might look into is native bash string-manipulation tools. There's rarely if ever a good reason to use `cut` in bash when you're only operating a line at a time -- the times you want to use cut is when you're operating _in bulk_, making it faster than [the shell's built-in string-manipulation primitives](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array `capture` is to contain the output, why not try something like ...

```
declare capture=() ; for item in $items; do 
    # some code
    capture+=( "$(echo "main/$category:${{ env.VERSION}}" | cut -d '/' -f2-)" )   
done
```

... and thereafter ...

```
local l ; for l in "${capture[@]}" ; do
  .
  .
  .
done
```

FWIW, I fail to see the point of the loop if the `$item` variable isn't used ... as [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) would have told you.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this depending on OP's expected result ...

**[worse]** Capturing the output into a single variable, with embedded linefeeds:

```
$ myvar=$(for item in $items; do echo "main/category/$item:$version" | cut -d '/' -f3-; done)          
$ typeset -p myvar
declare -- myvar="item1:1649947065
item2:1649947065
item3:1649947065"
```

**[worse]** Capturing the output into a single variable, linefeeds converted to spaces:

```
$ myvar=$(for item in $items; do echo "main/category/$item:$version" | cut -d '/' -f3-; done | tr '\n' ' ')
$ typeset -p myvar
declare -- myvar="item1:1649947065 item2:1649947065 item3:1649947065 "
```

---

Eliminating the subprocess call and the unnecessary `cut` ...

**[better]** Capturing the output into a single variable with a space between strings:and having the `for` loop append the text to the end of a variable:

```
$ delim=""
$ myvar=""

$ for item in $items
do
    myvar="${myvar}${delim}${item}:${version}"
    delim=" "
done

$ typeset -p myvar
declare -- myvar="item1:1649947065 item2:1649947065 item3:1649947065"
```

**[best]** Capturing the output into an array:

```
$ myarr=()

$ for item in $items
do
    myarr+=( "${item}:${version}" )
done

$ typeset -p myarr
declare -a myarr=([0]="item1:1649947944" [1]="item2:1649947944" [2]="item3:1649947944")
```

Comment: Might put the better-practice (array-based) approaches earlier in the answer than the worse ones.